# Mongodb server authentication not working

Tags: mongodb, authentication, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I have mongo db install on ec2  server and auth= true is turned on /etc/mongodb.conf but still any one can connect from remote using 
mongo ipaddress. So how to revoke this access and permit user via authentication only.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure users specifically to handle authentication. There is no authentication as such like mysql. Access mongo console and configure users, add those credentials to your application which should connect to mongodb server. Follow the below steps in mongo console.

```
use admin
db.addUser("username", "Password")
use another_database_name
db.addUser("project1", "Password")
```

Restart mongodb instance with authentication enabled.

```
mongod --auth --config /etc/mongodb/mongodb.conf
```

Comment: thanks for reply i have added users for each database but still it is connecting with test without authuntication.

Comment: Error reading config file: No such file or directory
mongod --auth --config /etc/mongodb.conf

Comment: Check in your installation, what is the actual path for mongodb.conf

Comment: did u tried with normal restart. Not sure why the path is not found